# Struct Tags for Comma-Separated Fields in Golang

Tags: go, struct

Say I have a struct like:

```
type MyType struct {
    A, B string
}
```

Can I put tags on these fields?  Obviously I could just put each field on its own line.  I'm just curious if it's possible to tag the fields in the original format.

Comment: Why not just try it and see?

Comment: Have you tried trying?

Comment: try that in your editor

Comment: Lol yes I have tried the different permutations I could think of.  Am I missing something obvious?

The following do not work
``tag:"a", "b"``
``tag:"a" "b"``
``tag:"a"` `tag:"b"``
``tag:"a"`, `tag:"b"``

Comment: Hello Harry welcome to Stackoverflow. When you say "the following do not work", please can you say what you were expecting and what you actually saw.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obviously specify a tag value for `MyType.A` and `MyType.B`, but you can't specify *different* tag values for those 2 fields (unless you list them in 2 separate field declarations).

Quoting from [Spec: Struct types:](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types)

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal *tag*, which becomes an attribute for **all the fields** in the corresponding field declaration.

A field declaration may only contain a single, optional tag:

> ```
> StructType    = "struct" "{" { FieldDecl ";" } "}" .
> FieldDecl     = (IdentifierList Type | EmbeddedField) [ Tag ] .
> EmbeddedField = [ "*" ] TypeName .
> Tag           = string_lit .
> ```

See this example:

```
type MyType struct {
    A, B string `mytag:"AB"`
}

m := MyType{"a", "b"}
t := reflect.TypeOf(m)

for _, fieldName := range []string{"A", "B"} {
    field, found := t.FieldByName(fieldName)
    if !found {
        continue
    }
    fmt.Printf("\nField: MyType.%s\n", fieldName)
    fmt.Printf("\tWhole tag value : %q\n", field.Tag)
    fmt.Printf("\tValue of 'mytag': %q\n", field.Tag.Get("mytag"))
}
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ZiaMRA-Xksv)):

```
Field: MyType.A
    Whole tag value : "mytag:\"AB\""
    Value of 'mytag': "AB"

Field: MyType.B
    Whole tag value : "mytag:\"AB\""
    Value of 'mytag': "AB"
```

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much. I definitely should have thought to check the spec and I think I remember reading that now.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can, but you can't tag the individual fields. From the [Language Reference](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Struct_types):

> A field declaration may be followed by an optional string literal tag, which becomes an attribute for all the fields in the corresponding field declaration

So you can say

```
type MyType struct {
  A, B string `my_tag`
}
```

but this will end up with both `A` and `B` being tagged with `my_tag`. For must common use cases (JSON, Protobuf, ...) this is not what you want.